# Use .styl file as dependency to compile another

Tags: gulp, dependencies, task, stylus

I have two files:

1 - **common.styl** (this file has imports that will be used on all pages of my project.)

```
@import 'utils/variables.styl'
@import 'utils/fonts.styl'
@import 'utils/mixin.styl'
```

2 - **home.styl** (this file is only for home section of my project and depends on common.styl)

```
body
  font-family CoolDown
  .box
    background $commonBg
```

In my gulpfile I've created two tasks, one to compile the common.styl and another to compile all the pages of my project.

**Common task:**

```
gulp.task('commonCSS', function () {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/common.styl')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.stylus({
      'include css': true,
      use: [jeet(), nib(), rupture()],
      import: ['jeet', 'nib', 'rupture']
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(stylBrowsers))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build + 'css'))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

My problem is the pages task, this only works if I put the common.styl file in the src path and concat them. But doing this way I need to put a name in the file. I would like to use the name of the current .styl being compiled.

```
gulp.task('pagesCSS', ['commonCSS'], function () {
  return gulp.src(['src/styles/common.styl', 'src/styles/pages/**/*.styl'])
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.concat('**page.css**')
    .pipe($.stylus({
      'include css': true,
      use: [ jeet(), nib(), rupture() ],
      import: ['jeet', 'nib', 'rupture']
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(stylBrowsers))
    .pipe($.minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build + 'css'))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
});
```

The question is: There is a way to include the common.styl to be used by pagesCSS task?

Maybe I'm missing something or using the wrong solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just `@import` or `@require` common.styl in those files? `@import "../../common"` and Stylus will include them for every page, no need for `concat`.

**Or...**

You can use `import` option you're already have in your config object. Stylus will include `common.styl` at the beginning of each file by itself.

First add `paths:  ['node_modules', 'src/styles']`. This way Stylus will know how to resolve paths for imports. You can probably skip this step if you provide full path in next one.

Now you can add your `common.styl` to `import: ['jeet', 'nib', 'rupture', 'common']`.

I'm using this configuration for my variables so I don't have to include them in each file.

Full example should look somewhat like that:

```
gulp.task('pagesCSS', ['commonCSS'], function () {
  return gulp.src('src/styles/pages/**/*.styl')    // <-- only pages styles are piped
    .pipe($.plumber())
    // .pipe($.concat('**page.css**')              // <-- remove this line
    .pipe($.stylus({
      'include css': true,
      use: [ jeet(), nib(), rupture() ],
      paths:  ['node_modules', 'src/styles']       // <-- resolve your styles path
      import: ['jeet', 'nib', 'rupture', 'common'] // <-- add your shared file
    }))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer(stylBrowsers))
    .pipe($.minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build + 'css'))
    .pipe(reload({ stream: true }));
});
```